# Best way to redraw a custom view when orientation changes

Tags: ios

I have a custom view:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(0, NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT , frame.size.width, 4 * ROW_HEIGHT + NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT + MESSAGE_BODY_PADDING);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        _selectionViewWidth = &frame.size.width;

        [self initView];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initView
{
    CGRect sectionSize = CGRectMake(0, 0 , *(_selectionViewWidth), ROW_HEIGHT * 4);
    _selectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sectionSize];
    [_selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

That I use in a View Controller the next way:

```
_mailAttributesView = [[MailAttributesView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _mailAttributesView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_mailAttributesView];
```

So when orientation changes from P to L I have the next problem:

[image]

What's the best way to get orientation change callback and redraw my custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to override your `UIView` `layoutSubviews` method and proceed to manually layout your subviews (looks like to/from/cc/subject controls) there.

Or, you could better configure your subview spring/struts (or autolayout constraints) for automatic layout.  You could do this in code or via a nib or storyboard.

**EDIT: additional info since you seem not to be getting layoutSubviews on orientation change.**

My guess is that the viewcontroller-view isn't resizing/repositioning your MailAttributes view either.

It's also not clear when/where you add your MailAttributesView to the veiwcontroller view.  If you're doing it in viewDidLoad your viewcontroller view may or may not have a valid frame size (depending if it was loaded from a nib or not).  It's best not to depend on the viewcontroller-view frame for layout purposes in viewDidLoad.

Rather, layout any viewcontroller-view subviews in viewWillLayoutSubviews.  There your viewcontroller-view frame will be set.

Others may point out that you can set your autoresizingFlags in viewDidLoad for any subviews, but there are gotcha's with this.  Primarily if the parent view has zero size, and your subviews are to be inset but have springs/struts defined to glue them to the parent view edges.

The best solution overall IMO is to setup autolayout constraints for everything contained in your viewcontroller view, on down.